# Content for Mapbox marker popups

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, rendering, mapbox-gl-js

Junior dev here!
Building a project with React (ts) and Mapbox.
I'm trying to render a marker popup with data from my own API with .setPopup() from the mapbox api.

Since I could not find a way to render a react component when clicking on a marker I use the .setHTML() from the mapbox api.

It worked fine until it was time to render arrays (one array with objects and one with strings).

I've tried mapping it out as I would in a tsx component and with pure ts + querySelectors and so on.
Either I get [Object, Object ] or nothing.

Anyone got any ideas? #desperate

Comment: access the members of the object when rendering using `obj['key']` or `obj.key` or `arr[$index]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.